# What is the sequence followed by the JVM when running a Java program?

Tags: java, jar, jvm, javac

I need to know what sequence the JVM follows when running a user program. Let's say the user has made a program **Runner.java** and has created a jar file for this named **runner.jar**.

Now if I

```
set classpath=%classpath%;c:\myapp.jar;%Java_Home%\lib\core.jar;runner.jar;
```

and I run the program from the command line:

```
java Runner
```

and the program runs. I need to know that the JVM will come from JVM base library -> Current Directory --> class path sequence, then it will run the program or some other sequence it will follow.

What will be the lookup sequence of the program?

Answer (score 1):

### Loading Sequence

Here's the sequence:

[image]

### The Current Directory vs. Classpath

By default, the **current directory is the class path**. However, once you set the CLASSPATH environment variable, it will [no longer be searched](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html).

> The default class path is the current directory. Setting the CLASSPATH variable or using the -classpath command-line option overrides that default, so if you want to include the current directory in the search path, you must include "." in the new settings.

If you want to include the current directory, add a dot.

[image]

The classpath is searched sequentially. You can move it anywhere to control whether you want it searched first or last, as illustrated by the above example.